# Convergence sequence out of nonexistent limit?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ is a probability space with probability measure $P$, $x(t,\omega)$ a random variable dependent on $t\in[0,T]$. $\forall \omega\in\Omega,\,\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\,x(t,\omega)\not\rightarrow0$. Does there exist a sequence $(t_k)_{k=1}^\infty\rightarrow0$ and a random variable $y$ satisfying either of the following conditions?

1. $y(\omega)\ne0,\,\forall\omega\in\Omega$, such that for any $\omega\in\Omega$, $x(t_k,\omega)\rightarrow y(\omega)$.
2. $\exists A\subset\Omega$, $P(A)>0,\,\ni \big(y(\omega)\ne0 
   \wedge x(t_k,\omega)\rightarrow y(\omega)\,\forall \omega\in A\big)$.

Comment: Do you allow $y(\omega)$ to be infinite?  Or is $x$ assumed to be bounded?

Comment: Let us say infinity is allowed. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Well, obviously if $x(t,\omega)\to\infty$ as $t\to 0$ you would have a problem...

Comment: I mean infinity is either permissible or not simultaneously for all functions, e.g. for both $x(t,\omega)$ and $y(\omega)$. No one is exceptional. :-) Do you see any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For instance, let the probability space be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and let $x(t,\omega)=1$ if $t\in [1/2^{n+1},1/2^n]$ and the $n$th binary digit of $\omega$ is $0$ and $x(t,\omega)=2$ otherwise.  For any particular sequence $(t_k)$ converging to $0$, you can choose some $\omega$ such that $x(t_k,\omega)=1$ for infinitely many $k$ and also $x(t_k,\omega)=2$ for infinitely many $k$ (just let the relevant binary digits of $\omega$ oscillate).

This is also a counterexample to your second condition.  For any $(t_k)$, the set of $\omega$ such that $x(t_k,\omega)$ converges has measure $0$ (since it is the set of numbers such that some particular infinite sequence of binary digits is either eventually $0$ or eventually $1$).

Comment: That is fast! I added a followup question, question #2, at the top. Would you please be so kind as to take a look? Thank you very much, Eric!

Comment: Hi, Eric. Care to take a look at my new questions https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2801027/64809 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2800921/64809? Thank you.