# Does every subsequence convergence almost surely imply convergence almost surely?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose $x(t,\omega): [0,T]\times\Omega\rightarrow \mathbf R$ is a random variable on a probability space $\Omega$. For every sequence $(t_k)_{k=1}^\infty\rightarrow 0$, $\exists$ a subsequence $(t_{k_i})_{i=1}^\infty$ independent of $\omega$  $\ni\big(\lim_\limits{i\rightarrow\infty}x(t_i,\omega)\rightarrow0$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega\big)$. Does this imply $\lim_\limits{t\rightarrow0}x(t,\omega)=0$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$?

What if we assume $\lim_\limits{t\rightarrow0}x(t,\omega)=0$ in probability?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2801027/64809) is a closely related question.

Answer (score 0):

Anthony Quas gave the following counterexample for the above question and the related one linked to in the question.

Let $\Omega$ be $[0,1)$, with probability measure $\mathbb P$ being Lebesgue measure. Set $x(t,\omega)=1$ if the fractional part of $1/t$ is $\omega$ and $0$ otherwise.