# Does every fast enough sequence convergence almost surely imply convergence almost surely?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose $x(t,\omega): [0,T]\times\Omega\rightarrow \mathbf R$ is a random variable on a probability space $\Omega$. Sequence $(t_k<2^{-k})_{k=1}^\infty \implies \lim_\limits{i\rightarrow\infty}x(t_i,\omega)\rightarrow0$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$. Does this imply $\lim_\limits{t\rightarrow0}x(t,\omega)=0$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$?

What if we assume $\lim_\limits{t\rightarrow0}x(t,\omega)=0$ in probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anthony Quas gave the following counterexample.

Let $\Omega$ be $[0,1)$, with probability measure $\mathbb P$ being Lebesgue measure. Set $x(t,\omega)=1$ if the fractional part of $1/t$ is $\omega$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: A system flag was raised for you having posted two identical answers. I guess the site software is trying to tell us that this is not ok. If the same answer works, may be the questions are duplicates of each other?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you for alerting me to this. I have deliberately linked the two questions because they are related. If you check the questions, the two are distinct. It so happens that the counterexample I posted answers both questions, which I have explicitly stated as much in the answer.

Comment: Where's the link?

Comment: @SheridanGrant: Sorry the link was somehow defunct and linking back to this exact problem. I can not find the original one. So I have now taken out that reference to the link in the answer. The answer is now self-contained.